# MySql query giving different result from editor and call statement

Tags: mysql

I have a query which is producing different results while executing from Workbench editor and calling the stored procedure from editor using call statement

The statement i am executing is as follows

```
SELECT 
    sum(PassCount) as PassCount, 
    sum(FailCount) as FailCount, 
    sum(NotAttempted) as NotAttempted, 
    sum(GoalAchieved) as GoalAchieved, 
    sum(B.AttemptCount) as AttemptCount, 
    @i as UserCount 
FROM usergoalachievement A 
JOIN userattemptcount B on B.GoalId=A.GoalId and B.UserProfileId=A.UserProfileId 
WHERE B.UserProfileId in (select distinct UserProfileId from usergrouprole WHERE RoleId=4 and GroupId=29) 
AND FIND_IN_SET(cast(A.GoalId as char),'30' ) and ifnull(ProgressionType,'')=ifnull(@progressionType,'PMP2') ;
```

NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL

now create a new procedure sp_test with the above statement and call the procedure using call statement from workbench as follows

```
call sp_test();
```

now the result will be as follows

'63', '214', '99', '0', '363', '0'

Why is this different for the same query (**usergoalachievement, userattemptcount are views**)

again apart for creating the stored procedure there is no change in the statements in editor and stored proc.

Can somebody explain why is this happening

Thanks everybody

Comment: Where do you define the user-defined variable? I can imagine that mysql set variable by default to 0 in procedures. Remove the variables and try again.

Comment: I got it working for the desired result, There is a problem with join. But still i can't understand why two results for the same query. cSteusloff even if you remove the user-defined variable the result is same. They are different